# Excel VBA - Find the address of maximum (or any specific value) in range, if the range containes DOUBLE values

Tags: excel, vba, double, comparison

The problem:

There is a range with double values. I would like to get the address of the maximum value.
I tried with the match function, but it can't compare doubles (gives false results), and my range isn't ordered.

There are ugly solutions (for example I can multiply my numbers by 10000, if I want 5 digit precision, then get the integer part and compare that, but it is very slow with more than 20000 rows) and maybe there are more elegant solutions.

Thanks :)

Sample Data: These are the numbers after Debug.Print

```
B 7.59999999999934E-02  
C 7.00000000000074E-02  
D 0.335000000000008  
E 8.19999999999936E-02  
F 8.49999999999937E-02  
G 7.39999999999981E-02  
H 5.49999999999926E-02  
I 0.070999999999998  
J 0.165000000000006  
K 7.59999999999934E-02
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: I think the best solution is to forget the max function of excel, and write my own maximum function, where I can track the address of the actual maximum number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just iterate your range and change a variable if the next cell double value is greater? Once you finish this range use the find to return cell row and column. See below

```
Dim i as Variant 
For Each i In Worksheets("yourWorkSheet").Range(Range("youStartCell"), Range("yourStartCell").End(xlDown)).Cells
  If i.Offset(-1) < i Then
      i = i.value
  End if
Next
```

Should look something like this. Need to handle the first row case in loop but if i did that you would have no work to do.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is very similar to a custom max function. I made some similar approach :)

Comment: I tried to upvote, but I have less than 15 reputation. I didn't use the site too many times so far. So the vote is disabled for me.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you! DM me if you run into VB problems, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

This is my final solution:

```
    'Find max and its address in range
Public Function maxAddress(rng As Range) As DoubleLong

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In rng
    If IsNumeric(cell.Value2) Then
        If cell.Value2 > maxAddress.db Then
            maxAddress.db = cell.Value2
            maxAddress.lg = cell.Row
        End If
    End If
Next cell
End Function
```

where is defined a type:

```
Public Type DoubleLong
    db As Double
    lg As Long
End Type
```